# Complete select list with optgroup in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select list that I complete by this way :

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
     $('#Cars').append('<option value="'+ index +'">'+ value +'</option>');
});
```

The data table look like this : `[{"0":"Ford","285":"Ferrari", "427":"Other"}]`

I want now add category in my select list. The table will look like this

```
["Cars":{"0":"Ford","285":"Ferrari", "427":"Other"},"Tractors":{"114":"Ferguson","115":"Others"}}]
```

Can you help me to make the jquery code I have try some but with no result.

I want my select box look like this in Html :
    `<optgroup label="Cars"> 
       <option>Ford</option> 
       <option>Ferrari</option> 
       <option>Other</option> 
    </optgroup> 
    <optgroup label="Tractors"> 
       <option>Ferguson</option> 
       <option>Other</option> 
    </optgroup>`

Comment: can you post how should your select box look like?

Comment: isn't `Cars` key an array `[]` or if its object, `0` `285` are dynamic keys or static ?

Comment: cars is the key of the array with all the values. the keys are static and come from my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try loop through your nested hash:

```
var select = '';
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
   select += '<optgroup label="'+ key +'">'
   $.each(value, function(k, v) {
       select += '<option value="'+ k +'">'+ v +'</option>'
   })
   select += '</optgroup>'
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q31z2yr5/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k3wmg08t/1/)

your initial data should be properly formatteed associative array:

```
var items = {"Cars":{"0":"Ford","285":"Ferrari", "427":"Other"},"Tractors":{"114":"Ferguson","115":"Others"}};
```

and using 'for in' loop you solve your task.

```
for(catName in items)
{ 
    var optGroup = $("<optgroup />", {
        label: catName
    });
    for(propName in items[catName])
    {
        var option = $("<option />", {
            text: items[catName][propName],
            value: propName
        });
        optGroup.append(option);
    }
    $("#Cars").append(optGroup);
}
```

Comment: The result looks like the first answer. The 2 solutions works well, but what is the best one?